# 403 Response for images in relative parent path of inline CSS

Tags: html, css, http, amazon-route53

In the `<style>` section (no physical CSS file) of the login page for my router's web interface, there is a CSS declaration which contains:

```
background: url("../img/login/logo.png")
```

As most router's web interfaces are, this main page is accessible from the router's IP address (192.168.0.1:80 in this case). The page loads fine in chrome, and the image is displayed correctly. Chrome indicates that it received this image from `http://192.168.0.1/img/login/logo.png`. However, whenever I load this url in browser, or try to mimic the request in postman, I get a 403 response. You can see the response info [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHvmL.png)

This same issue propagates whenever I try to setup an `A` record in Route 53 to point to my home network's IP address. The images (and more of the scripts in the site which load with relative paths) do not load, and are shown as 403'd in chrome's request/response information. The only difference is the Request URL is my domain  `http://myrouter.example.com:1337/img/login/logo.png`, and the remote address is my home network's IP, as well as the referrer. The rest of the login page loads fine with this configuration, it seems only the relative paths are failing.

What would cause this? I understand that 403 is the server deciding to reject the request, so it is getting through to the router, but not responding with the image.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the web server cares about the HTTP_HOST variable and will only serve when accessed via the numeric IP address. This is typical practice by net admins to prevent DNS rebind attacks. I use PFSense and it's setup that way by default.

You may or may not be able to override this feature on your router, but most SoHo routers will not allow this. If you want more configurability (and you seem like a knowledgeable user), I highly recommend using PFSense!

Comment: That would make sense to me as well, except that I was able to setup a NO-IP `A` record to point to the IP address of my home network, which you would expect to create the same result as the `A` record in Route 53. However, the images load correctly without a 403 error. This stumps me.

Answer (score 0):

It could be as simple as a referrer check by the web server. I see you've posted the headers for the 200 OK response but not the 403 response. A simple diff of the two should reveal the cause.

Comment: I'll attach the other [here](https://i.imgur.com/WGw2UJ4.png). You can see that the public address of my home network is resolving correctly. When I load that IP address manually (eg. 47.X.X.X:1337), the page loads correctly and the images resolve.

I'm still slightly confused that the image's url refers to the parent directory, but chrome shows this as not going up one directory at all.